# How can I refactor a lot of similar nested loops in my Matrix class?

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix, refactoring

How can I properly refactor my Matrix class where nearly all the methods I use in this class have double nested loops which all look almost exactly the same?

Here are two of many methods that I wish to include in this class. It's going to be unnecessarily long if I don't find a better way to deal with this.

```js
randomize() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.rows; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < this.cols; j++) {
            this.matrix[i][j] = Math.random();
        }
    }
}

add(n) {
    if (n instanceof Matrix) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.matrix.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < this.matrix[i].length; j++) {
                this.matrix[i][j] += n.matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.matrix.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < this.matrix[i].length; j++) {
                this.matrix[i][j] += n;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does `this.rows == this.matrix.length` ? and does `this.cols == this.matrix[].length`? i assumed the matrix arrays rectangular (ie all rows have same column count)?

Comment: Yes, they are rectangular.

Comment: how does `this.rows` / `this.cols` relate to the dimensions of `this.matrix` ?

Comment: this is just a property of the object. Allowed me to avoid these lengthy this.matrix[i].length. Makes it clean eg. when checking for the validity of matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a higher-order function, which receives a function to be called on each element and returns the new value to replace it.

In my example below, the callback function also receives the indexes, so it can use them to reference another matrix, which is needed in the `add` method.

```js
updateEach(callback) {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.rows; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < this.cols; j++) {
      this.matrix[i][j] = callback(this.matrix[i][j], i, j);
    }
  }
}

randomize() {
  this.updateEach(() => Math.random());
}

add(n) {
  if (n instanceof Matrix) {
    this.updateEach((oldval, i, j) => oldval + n.matrix[i][j]);
  } else {
    this.updateEach((oldval) => oldval + n)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Barmar's answer just with a different flavor:

```
// Specify the limits for i, j, and then pass in a function
// which takes the index parameters.
function loop(iMax, jMax, fn) {
    for (let i = 0; i < iMax; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < jMax; j++) {
            fn(i, j);
        }
    }
}

function randomize() {
    loop(this.rows, this.columns, (i, j) => {
        this.matrix[i][j] = Math.random();
    });
}

function add(n) {
    if (n instanceof Matrix) {
      loop(this.matrix.length, this.matrix[0].length, (i, j) => {
          this.matrix[i][j] += n[i][j];
      });
    }
}
```

This more generic approach allows you to do whatever you want with the loop indices. You *could* do reassignment, or you could log out the matrix values, or assign them to a new matrix.

```
loop(this.rows, this.cols, (i, j) => {
  console.log(this.matrix[i][j]);
});
```

```
loop(this.rows, this.cols, (i, j) => {
    that.matrix = this.matrix[i][j];
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution seems interesting, but Barmars solution will be of more use to me. Might come back to this solution in later projects.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function.

```js
class Matrix {
  constructor(arr) {
    this.matrix = arr;
    this.rows = arr.length;
    this.cols = arr[0].length;
  }
  loop(func, arr2, arr2Recurse) {
    this.matrix = this.matrix.map((row, i) =>
      row.map((col, j) => func(col, arr2Recurse ? arr2.matrix[i][j] : arr2))
    );
  }
  randomize() {
    this.loop(() => Math.random());
  }
  add(n) {
    this.loop((el, nEl) => (el += nEl), n, n instanceof Matrix);
  }
}
var a = new Matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]]);
var b = new Matrix([[5, 6], [7, 8]]);
a.add(b);
console.log(a);
a.add(1);
console.log(a);
a.randomize();
console.log(a);
```

Comment: These functions do not work. In "loop" the arguments are not passed correctly to func. In randomize, you don't actually do a reassignment of any value in the matrix. Add reassigns the column index that's passed in, not the matrix value.

Comment: @Michael Thanks. I believe I fixed it.